# Generate Java projects with Ruby

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I'd like to build a Rails site that generates a complete Android app. I already wrote the app, but I want the generator to be able to insert different api keys for each new app.

Of course none of this is Android/Java specific. Given some files I already wrote, how can I use those as a template to generate new files, and maybe even put them into a .zip for download?

Comment: Templates are templates; if they're evaluated in a context that has the data you need, you can do what ever you want with the output, including zip and stream back to the user. You may need to be more specific.

Comment: Alright, then. So I can use ERB templates to generate a folder of files that can be downloaded? What tools can help me do this? I'm not sure why this question is getting downvoted.

Comment: I don't know either, but to me it seems like if the user had the ability to specify enough information to generate an app skeleton template, they'd be able to create something more firmly targeted at their needs just as easily instead of modify/extend what you provide. Could just be that they figure if you're writing an app generator app you know enough to be able to find out how to write evaluated templates to a directory and zip them up on your own.

Answer (score 2):

What tools?

Either the normal render mechanism (you may render to, and persist, a string), or any Ruby template engine (erb, mustache, whatever).

Personally, I'd separate the code generation templates from anything Rails-related. That may be unwarranted bias, but IMO it would be more maintainable, and more obvious. It also allows an easier means of using the same logic outside of Rails.

You can evaluate them and write them to a directory, then use something like the rubyzip gem to zip them up. Use the normal rails send_file (or whatever it is) to stream the file back to the client.